# Why the ellipse circumference shows minor axis as 10 times?

Tags: conic-sections

Ellipse of having minor axis 0.692200628 and major axis 1.444667861 has circumference 6.9229....... which seems quite close to be minor axis 0.6922006.... multiplied by 10 but deviation occurs at 6.922''9''... after ''22''? Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have here is a coincidence!

You might also notice that if $a = 0.692200628$ and $b = 1.444667861$, then we have $ab = 1.000000000635616708$ which is remarkably close to 1. This is also a coincidence, unless there is some reason why these numbers should be connected in any way due to the method by which they calculated in the first place.

Comment: no multiplying them is not related. I want to know how 10 have plunged into the scenario.

Comment: If you examine my answer carefully, you will see that I didn't claim that multiplying them was related! I claimed it was a coincidence.

Comment: where is coincidence?

Comment: It is a coincidence that if you choose $a$ and $b$ to have the values you gave, then $ab$ is very close to being 1. Unless there is some reason why you have chosen exactly these numbers, it is just a coincidence.

Comment: It is also a pure coincidence that the "10 has plunged into the scenario". Without further information about the origin of $a$ and $b$, it could just as easily happened that the circumference would be almost exactly 19 times $a$, or any other multiple.